# Load table with GEOMETRY column to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, geopandas, pandas

I am trying to load table (from Postgres DB) with GEOMETRY column to Pandas DataFrame using `pd.read_sql_table` method. I am getting error becuase GEOMETRY type seem to be not supported:

*C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\base.py:3010: SAWarning: Did not recognize type 'geometry' of column 'geometry'
  "Did not recognize type '%s' of column '%s'" % (attype, name)*

Does anyone knows how to load such data to Pandas df? On Pandas Doc page for "read_sql_table" I don't see options to define data type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GeoPandas](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) adds spatial datatypes/methods to pandas. I would install that and use the [from_postgis](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis) method:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
sql = "SELECT ST_asBinary(geom) AS geom, highway FROM roads"
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(sql, con)
```